# How to compute the probability of the union of an infinite number of events?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Consider the event "I am currently being seen by anyone" to be $s$. I am interested in estimating the probability $P(s|\vec{x})$ (where $\vec{x}$ is where I am at the moment), from the conditional probabilities of someone to be seeing me from the position $\vec{y}$. (Imagine that I am playing the hide and seek game, that I am optimizing my location for winning at hiding, and I have some clues of where the seekers might try to go).

My current approach is this:

- define the event "I am currently being seen by someone at $\vec{y}$" as $s(\vec{y})$.
- Assume that events are independent, i.e. $P(s(\vec{y}_i),s(\vec{y}_j)|\vec{x}) = P(s(\vec{y}_i)|\vec{x})P(s(\vec{y}_j)|\vec{x})$
- conclude that the event $s$ is the union of the all events $s(\vec{y}_i)$.
- Thus, $$P(s(\vec{y})|\vec{x}) = \int P(s(\vec{y})|\vec{x})d\vec{y}$$

My issue is that this equation does not look right to me. I mean, for a numerable set of events, P(union) = sum of P(individuals), but I am not sure how this works for unions of uncountable events.

Is the formalization above correct? If not, what is the way to formalize this problem in continuous space?

Comment: Note that *P(Union) = Sum of P* is not at all true in general, it's only true when the events are disjoint.

Comment: I've expanded my answer with some ideas on how to correctly calculate your probability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an uncountable family of events are mutually independent (any finite subfamily of them is mutually independent), and each has a non-zero probability of occurring, then the probability of at least one of them occurring is $1$: flip an uncountable number of coins and you'll always get heads eventually.

Let $(A_i)$ be your family of events, indexed over some uncountable set $I$. Then for some $\epsilon>0$, there are infinitely many $A_i$ with $P(A_i)\geq\epsilon$. Now apply Borel-Cantelli or some other such argument to show that the probability of one of those events occuring is $1$. To see that my claim is true for some $\epsilon$, let $\mathcal A_n=\{A_i|P(A_i)\geq\frac1n\}$. The union of the $\mathcal A_n$ is the family of all $A_i$, thus one of the $\mathcal A_n$ must be infinite, otherwise we would have expressed an uncountable family as the union of countably many finite families.

You may also find [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2517384/probability-of-union-of-events/2517449#2517449) and my answer to it interesting.

For a reasonable model for this situation, maybe this will give you some ideas. Assume the population is very densely packed, with a population density function $\rho(x)$. Suppose that the probability a person *does not* see you depends only on their position, according to the function $f(x)$. What is the probability that *nobody* in a given small area around a point $x$ sees you? If $f$ is continuous, it's basically $f(x)^n$, where $n$ is the number of people in that area. Taking a logarithm, we get

$$\log P(\text{nobody sees you}) = n\log f(x) = a\rho(x)\log f(x)$$

where $a$ is the area of the small region we're interested in. Taking the logarithm was important so that we could divide by $a$ and obtain a density:

$$\frac {\log P(\text{nobody sees you})} a = \rho(x) \log f(x)$$

thus, for any region $A$

$$\log P(\text{nobody in $A$ sees you})=\int_A \rho(x) \log f(x) dx$$

and in particular

$$P(\text{somebody sees you})=1-\exp\left(\int_{\mathbb R^2} \rho(x)\log f(x)dx\right)$$

Comment: Thank you very much for expanding the answer. That was what I was trying to obtain. My situation is the opposite: the density is very small on a majority of places, and only high on a very small number of places (e.g. gaussians centered around some places like places with good visibility). I formulated my question poorly, so I will re-formulate in a new question, just focused on formulating the problem.

Comment: I tried to formulate the problem in this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2842509/how-to-formulate-the-hide-and-seek-problem-in-continuous-space. FYI, your formulation seems related to the notion of [Product Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_integral)